# Error with copying values from one sheet to other

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to copy the values from some cells but it give me this error, i tried even without using the def cell(x,y) but still the same error.

This is the error:

```
learn_tar.cell(row=learn_tar, column=1).value = sheet.cell(row=learn_tar, column=1).value
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cell'
```

Source:

```
import openpyxl 

def cell(x,y):
   cell = sheet.cell(row=x,column=y).value
   return cell; 

def percentage(percent, whole):
  return int((percent * whole) / 100.0);


ex = openpyxl.load_workbook("Final_excel2.xlsx")
sheet = ex.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

num = [0,0,0]
per = [0,0,0]

for row in range(2,4798):

    if cell(row,1) == '1: Progression':
        num[0] = num[0] + 1
    elif cell(row,1) == '2: Incidence':
        num[1] = num[1] + 1
    elif cell(row,1) == '3: Non-exposed control group':
        num[2] = num[2] + 1

    for column in range(2,49):
       #doing stuff

per[0] = percentage(70,num[0])
per[1] = percentage(70,num[1])
per[2] = percentage(70,num[2])

learn_att = ex.create_sheet('Learn-Att',2)
learn_tar = ex.create_sheet('Learn-Tar',3)

test_att = ex.create_sheet('Test-Att',4)
test_tar = ex.create_sheet('Test-Tar',5)

learn_att = 1
learn_tar = 1

test_att = 1
test_tar = 1



for row in range(2,4798):

    if row<=1391:
        if row<=974:                
            learn_tar.cell(row=learn_tar, column=1).value = cell(row,1)
            learn_att+= 1
            learn_tar+= 1
        else:
            test_tar.cell(row = test_tar,column = 1).value = cell(row,1)
            test_att+= 1
            test_tar+= 1

    for column in range(2,49):

        if row<=1391:
            if row<=974:                
                learn_att.cell(row = learn_att,column = column - 1).value = cell(row,column)
            else:
                test_att.cell(row = test_att,column = column - 1).value = cell(row,column)
```

Comment: If you use `iter_rows()` your code will be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override `learn_tar` with `1`:

```
learn_tar = ex.create_sheet('Learn-Tar',3)
...
learn_tar = 1
```

Remove:

```
learn_tar = 1
```

and:

```
learn_tar+= 1
```

from your code.